# How to store large number of unknown length in array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store a large number using arrays. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main(){
    char number[10];
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        std::cin >> number[i];
        size++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        std::cout << "number[" << i << "]: " << number[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

This works fine when I enter a number with exactly 10 digits, but if I enter a number less than that then my program will just hang because it's waiting for me to enter all 10 digits.

Is there a way to detect when the user presses Enter? Or some way of telling the for loop to break when the user inputs the entire number?

Comment: You could add `if ( !std::isdigit(number[i], std::locale()) ) break;` after reading the digit. With `#include <locale>`. But it would be more normal for you to read a `string` and then process the string.

Comment: If all you're doing is inputting numbers into a character buffer, you'd might as well just use `std::string` which behaves as you're expecting with `cin`

Comment: I once read somewhere in SO that it's well mannered to know how big you'll need your array beforehand. Maybe asking the user to input the number of digits the number will have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to take input without loop as this is a number otherwise the user   has to input a digit and then put a space or enter to input the next digit and so on. Rather user will be wanting to input the number on a go without space and enter.

But in this method you will not be able to check whether user gives a valid digit during input ! You have to traverse the number array again to check each digit !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char number[10];
    int size = 0;
    cin >> number;
    size=strlen(number); // number of digits entered

    cout << "Number of digits entered: " << size << endl;
    cout << "Entered Number is: " << number;
}
```